# Implement *FIND* friends in parse.com

Tags: ios, parse-platform

There are multiple examples on the net to implement friend/follower relationships between users. But I am unable to find a clever solution to search for the friends. Every example assumes that I  selected the user objects already but it has no example how to find them prior to that.

Given an application that allows ad-hoc registration, combined with facebook/twitter login what would be the search criteria? Username does not work because finding a user registered with facebook is not possible as facebook logins won't have a usable and easy to remember username. Natural name will lead to too many "John Smiths" so I do not like the idea again. Email address sounds reasonable (as it can be extracted from facebook profile and we can ask email verification for ad-hoc registrations) but with that I have a bit of security concerns: is there a risk that someone reads the whole database storing the email addresses? Also how do I store those addresses? Do I store them in a separate class with a pointer to the user object? But then how do I prevent the "hackers" from reading the whole list?

Comment: Every Parse object, including the `PFUser`s class has a unique `objectID`. Simply query the `User` class and and use `currentUser.objectID` to get a read-only `String`. In the model you are talking about have each `User` have an array of friends, then just add these user `objectId`'s to the arrays.

Comment: @KyleH: please read the question. I am not asking how to create and store the relationships. I am asking how to FIND friends.